# How to set object to world origin?

Tags: transforms

blender 2.81
I accidentally moved an object and can not undo it. How may I move the object to the world origin, and/or set the location of the object at the center of x, y, or z axes.

Answer (score 17):

You press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to set your *Cursor to World Origin*, then you can select your object and press once again <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. This time select *Selection to Cursor*, which will snap your selected object to the cursor that is now located at the world origin.

To make new objects aligned to the center x, y and z axis, which is essentially at origin, just set the cursor back to origin. Thus new objects will be created there.

For completeness sake, setting the cursor to origin can also be done with the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> shortcut, which avoids the pie-menu.

Answer (score 2):

In the *Object* menu, *Clear / Location* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)

Comment: That's essentially the same thing than Moog's answer, just quicker ; so the limitation pointed by batFINGER still applies

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw in a different option than using cursors ...

If you have the item panel open in the right hand side, then you can click and drag over the *Location* fields X,Y,Z and hit 0 then enter.

Comment: To clarify the location property of an object is relative to its parent. Above will work for object with no parent, or with parent located at (0, 0, 0).  Codewise to set an object to global origin `ob.matrix_world.translation = (0, 0, 0)` will set the local coordinates accordingly.