# Origin problem doesn't change

Tags: origin

I need to mirror my object using the World Origin as reference but I can't change the object's origin. If I mirror using the object's origin, the mirror is completely wrong. How can I change this? I have tried to modify the origin using edit, origin, and 3D Cursor but it doesn't work. What can I do? I need to use the blue line as reference for the mirror.

[image]

Comment: please share a screenshot to demonstrate your problem

Comment: I have done it.

Comment: Show an image of the whole screen. We can't see where your 3D cursor is in the image you've posted. You can save an image in Blender via Window > Save Screenshot.

Comment: maybe apply the rotation in Object mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160343/how-to-set-object-to-world-origin

Comment: just `Ctrl+A` and choose Apply All Transforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use another object like an empty placed wherever you wish as Mirror Object if you wish the object's origin to remain unchanged.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In **Object mode**:
Click on *Affect only Origins*:

[image]

Then move origin using regular tools

[image]

Don't forget to uncheck *Affect only Origins* when it's done